# How to save your results from screen output to csv file in 2 columns on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

with open('predictions.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    next(csvreader)
    for r in csvreader:
        df = r[:-1]
        a = float(str(df[:][0]))
        b = float(str(df[:][1]))
        if a > b :
            print(1, 0)
        else:
            print(0, 1)

0 1
0 1
0 1
0 1
0 1
0 1
```

I printed my result from predictions.csv file, and I'm trying to save my result, that showed as 0 and 1, to CSV file in 2 columns. So how can I save my result to a CSV file of 2 columns as it showed?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We won't write the code for you, but a quick google will show you some [examples that you can adapt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to save the printed output - you can directly save the data to a CSV when you're printing it in the loop, like this:

```
with open('new_file.csv', mode='a', newline='') as file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file)
    if a > b :
        print(1, 0)
        csv_writer.writerow(['1', '0'])
    else:
        print(0, 1)
        csv_writer.writerow(['0', '1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%%capture cap --no-stderr
with open('predictions.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    next(csvreader)
    for r in csvreader:
        df = r[:-1]
        a = float(str(df[:][0]))
        b = float(str(df[:][1]))
        with open('output.csv', 'w') as writer:
            if a > b :
                print(1,',',0)
            else:
                print(0,',',1)
            writer.write(cap.stdout)
```